# How to switch libjpeg9 used in Pillow3.1.1 to libjpeg8?

Tags: python-imaging-library, libjpeg

Background

My final objective is to run https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans/blob/master/h5tool.py

which requires Pillow3.1.1 with libjpeg8.
It occurred an error when checking the MD5 of the first image of the dataset.
It seems to be caused by the different version of libjpeg used in Pillow.
I use the libjpeg9 in Pillow3.1.1 while the suggested version is libjpeg8.
I tested it on the other machine and got these results:

On MY machine

```
# python
import hashlib
from PIL import Image
md = hashlib.md5()
md.update(Image.open('000001.jpg').tobytes())
print(md.hexdigest())
# 92a0d5f96769de4e68a0ce40e7f0c13f
# It is incorrect
```

On the other machine

```
# python
import hashlib
from PIL import Image
md = hashlib.md5()
md.update(Image.open('000001.jpg').tobytes())
print(md.hexdigest())
# 9cad8178d6cb0196b36f7b34bc5eb6d3
# It is correct.
```

However, when I tried to use md5sum to check these two images on different machines, I got the same code. That means files are exactly the same. So I think the problem might be the version of libjpeg.

On MY machine

```
ldd /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe4e3f6000)
**libjpeg.so.9 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/libjpeg.so.9 (0x00007fbeb418a000)**
libz.so.1 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbeb3f74000)
libtiff.so.5 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fbeb3cf6000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fbeb38fa000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbeb36dc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbeb3313000)
liblzma.so.5 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/./liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbeb30ee000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbeb2ee6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbeb2be0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbeb29dc000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fbeb27d9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbeb4631000)
```

On the other machine

```
$ldd /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff4791000)
**libjpeg.so.8 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/../../../libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f217847f000)**
libz.so.1 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/../../../libz.so.1 (0x00007f2178268000)
libtiff.so.5 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/../../../libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f2177fea000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/../../../libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f2177bf0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f21779b5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21775f4000)
liblzma.so.5 => /home/liyh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/../../.././liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f21773ce000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f21771c6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2176ec4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2176cc0000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2176abc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f217890e000)
```

I tried to re-install Pillow==3.1.1, but it kept using libjpeg9 instead of libjpeg8.

If I delete the /home/liyh/anaconda2/envs/theano/lib/libjpeg.so.9 and add libjpeg.so.8 into the directory and re-install Pillow==3.1.1, I got

```
ImportError: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My question is:

- How can I install Pillow3.1.1 with libjpeg8, or
- How can I generate the correct MD5 code using libjpeg9, or
- What other possible reasons that cause the different MD5 code?

Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
Python 2.7

Edited:
The image I used is the first image (000001.jpg) in [CelebA dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html) ("in-the-wild" version, not the "align&cropped").

```
$md5sum /data2/pub_data/CelebA/Img/img_celeba/000001.jpg
39d4f4f149cf541601ad334ea98c822d
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to solve this problem by installing `pillow==3.1.1` with `conda` instead of `pip`. In this way, pillow uses libjpeg8 as its jpeg decoder as we want.

```
conda create -n new_env
source activate new_env    
conda install pillow==3.1.1
conda install ...(other needed libs)
```

Comment: Nice to see that you solved, but it's a bit troubling that libjpeg8 and libjpeg9 provide different image data... Could you upload your data file for further examination and possibly to open a bug?

Comment: @MatteoItalia The image I used is the first image (000001.jpg) in CelebA dataset ("in-the-wild" version, not the "align&cropped"). I am not sure if I am legally allowed to upload it here. You can download and examine it. Also, I added the "md5sum" code of this image at the end of the question.